# Intersection of types reducing to never

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a not very complex type with a field that depends on the type of another field which is a union of identifier strings. At some point, when there is not enough information about which value of this union is present the compiler fails resolving the type to never.

This is some simplified code of what I'm trying:

```js
type TextSectionContent = {
  data: string
}

type ImageSectionContent = {
  url: string
}

type GuideSectionMap = {
  text: TextSectionContent
  image: ImageSectionContent
}

type GuideSectionType = keyof GuideSectionMap

type GuideSection<T extends GuideSectionType> = {
  type: T
  content: GuideSectionMap[T]
}

type Guide = {
  sections: GuideSection<GuideSectionType>[]
}
```

Then I'm trying to call the correct function for a section:

```js
const componentForSection: {
    [key in GuideSectionType]: (section: GuideSection<key>) => void;
} = {
    text: (section) => {},
    image: (section) => {},
};

function example(section: GuideSection<GuideSectionType>) {
    componentForSection[section.type](section); // error here
}
```

The body of `example` isn't working because `section` is being transformed to `never` because property `type` has conflicting types in some constituents.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewDKEDGwCWB7AdgYV2Ah2CgF4oBvAKCjqgBMBDYJgLigGdgAnDHAOYBuagF8R1UJCgBJALZMBEFOmz5CxUhRr0oAVx4AbDtz6CR46pPDQA4nowNlaTLgCyTMOSq16RRBxwiCqu6iSaIroYCkoc8orOqrgE4SQWElJ2Dk4hajA23gDWECBYAGZQ9o6JoR5gGQVVOS5qADwwUAhEOAycldk1eTYAfN46fjaBkfSoGiQcTYPungDaMAC66VaZ-dVjvnScLbicCwO5uK2LFzj5kMMrm2ISszjcULNyYLiaAGJYPBuHHGdBWxRAUH4u2aSVuNnWHAAFEdYWdqjdWuDhgBKcijABuWEcFn2un8wCRKNCuLIo0oogANAdITEIJTjjgaXTGc8rGU9DhYZ14EwvoYIMiOWiYaErucOXcIDifLpPt8cH8ATcVlS1AA6TLrSWw7EWahAA)

Comment: I have removed all references to React from this post as it is not necessary to demonstrate the problem. If you feel that React is relevant to this post, you may [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75756193/revisions) the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you break down your `GuideSection<T>` with `T = GuideSectionType` becomes

```js
{
  type: 'text' | 'image'
  content: GuideSectionMap['text' | 'image'] // this is your problem      
}
```

As you can see you're trying to access the map with both keys at the same time, which cannot be resolved, so your type becomes `never`.

To fix it, you have to make your function generic and allow typescript to infer the type, which you can do like this:

```js
function example<T extends GuideSectionType>(section: GuideSection<T>) {
    componentForSection[section.type](section);
}
```

Comment: (for OP, this means that you should make your React component generic.)

Comment: Wrapping the `componentForSection[section.type](section)` in a generic function like in this answer and then calling it from the React component works as well. I was missing this little last help to the compiler but I didn't know what exactly it was asking me for :)

Comment: Oh yeah, typescript errors are absolutely horrible to debug. So breaking down types in its most rudimentary parts helps me with understanding what goes wrong.